# Rails - Postgres and JSON PG::InvalidTextRepresentation with SQL views

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, activerecord

I have a Rails app deployed with a Docker container on App Engine with PG11.
I'm using a non-materialized SQL view generated by Scenic called `formatted_bookings`.
This view returns many fields, including a JSON object `places`generated by another SQL view using `json_agg` and `jsonb_build_object`.
The query works fine with SQL, and it returns a bunch of rows like this one (there are many other columns):

```
booking_id | country_id | country_name |  places     
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------    
     1     |     23     |     "Spain"  | [{id: 34, name: "Some name"}, {id: 54, name: "Another"}, {id: 34, name: null}]
```

I use Scenic so that I can run.

```
FormattedBooking.where(booking_id: 1)
```

or with SQL I can run

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("SELECT * FROM formatted_bookings WHERE booking_id = 1")
```

In local, everything works correctly.
In both cases tho, in prod, I get an error message:

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (PG::InvalidTextRepresentation: ERROR:  invalid input syntax for integer: "Some name").
```

It seems like PG is expecting an integer as a name. The code works correctly if I run the same query in prod querying the `country_id` or any other columns instead of the `booking_id`.

```
FormattedBooking.where(country_id: 1) # Returns the expected object in an ActiveRecord relation

ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("SELECT * FROM formatted_bookings some_attribute = XXXX") #returns a PG result
```

Another thing that works, for example, to get `booking_id = 10`

```
FormattedBooking.where("booking_id > ? AND booking_id < ?", 9, 11)
```

I pulled the prod DB in local, and everything works as expected. Local and Prod are running in the same Docker env, and the gem versions are the same.

On top of that, and this is what confuses me the most, if I SSH in the prod instance, open the rails console, and run the broken query, it crashes 5 or 6 times, and then it starts working correctly out of nowhere.

I'm confused because I don't understand where the problem could come from.
And the fact that it starts to work 'magically' after a few crashes it's even more strange. Any idea what the reason could be?

Comment: Nothing strange in terms of Gem/ Libraries. I use Sidekiq/Redis and Foreman + Procfile to run everything. ```psql``` works fine. In general, I've never had other crashes. 
Now I managed to patch it changing the ```where(booking_id: xx)``` to ```("booking_id > ? AND booking_id < ?", id - 1, id + 1)```. But still, I'd like to make sure to find the issue :)